# Can’t perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target

Tags: xcode-instruments

I am getting `error` while playing recorded script through Instruments like
`Can’t perform action on invalid element: UIAElementNil from target`.

Sometime its work if i kill the running application instance. Is there any way to avoid this kind of issue ? or any permanent solution for this kind of issue?